# Why wont my elements fade in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far my website that I am doing only animates text that is specified in "var txt".

My issue is trying to get the following elements(an image and some text) to fade in after the first function (typeWriter) is finished executing.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Test';
    var speed = 50;
    window.onload = function typeWriter(callback){
        if (i < txt.length){
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(function(){typeWriter(callback)}, speed);
        }else if(typeof callback == 'function'){
         callback();
        }
    }
    function fader(){
        $("#fade").fadeIn("slow");
    }

    typeWriter(callback);

<!-- Html below -->

    <div class="subSection">
    <div id="fade">
        <h2 id="type"></h2>
        <img src="ring.jpg" alt="rings">
        <p>Now comes in a range of different colours and sizes.<br>Pricing from €149.99</p>
        <p><a href=order.html class="button">Buy Now</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your JS code is malformed-- looks like a missing bracket.

Comment: If `callback` is expected to happen after the typeWriter has finished, that is not going to happen as you are trying to call the callback after the first iteration.  You probably want to do that as an else to your if (i < txt.length) conditional

Comment: Also `typeWriter(fader());` should be `typeWriter(fader);` so you are not invoking the fader.

Comment: @Taplar just added that as an else and fixed the typeWriter. Still not working...

Comment: You didn't keep your check to make sure that the callback is a function.  It will not be defined for the on load.

Comment: @Taplar still nothing...

Comment: `}else{
            (typeof callback == 'function'){` is malformed if else statement. maybe use `}else if(typeof callback == 'function'){` you are also not passing the callback function through the setTimeout. use something like `setTimeout(function(){typeWriter(callback)}, speed);`

Comment: `typeWriter(fader);` Is now undefined. I didnt think animating stuff was so difficult.

Comment: yes, use `callback` not `fader`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: typeWriter is not defined is the error I am getting for `typeWriter(callback);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the intial syntax errors, there were some issues to solve. The onload will fire and pass its own arguments, not the callback you want. So instead wrap it in a callback function and call the function with the chosen callback. Alternatively use `onload = typeWriter.bind(null, fader)` which passes fader as the callback function. Next you want to set the `#fade` element to `display: none` in your css so it starts hidden, and then move your txt `#type` outside the fade div, so it is visible and you can see the auto-typing animation you made.

You can define the `typeWriter` as a function, and then call it in the `window.onload` event:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Test';
var speed = 50;
function typeWriter(callback){
  if (i < txt.length){
    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(function(){typeWriter(callback)}, speed);
  } else if(typeof callback == 'function'){
    callback();
  }
}
function fader(){
  $("#fade").fadeIn("slow");
}
window.onload = function(){
  typeWriter(fader);
}
```

```css
#fade {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="subSection">
  <h2 id="type"></h2>
  <div id="fade">
    <img src="ring.jpg" alt="rings">
    <p>Now comes in a range of different colours and sizes.<br>Pricing from €149.99</p>
    <p><a href=order.html class="button">Buy Now</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Noface was faster than me, but since my solution is different, I still feel like posting it. The major difference is that it does not expose global variables. That means that you can have multiple instances of it running on a page.

Here you go:

```js
function typeWriter(options) {
  // Getting options or using default values
  var settings = {
    element: options.element,
    text: options.text || "Typewriter",
    speed: options.speed || 100,
    complete: options.complete || function() {}
  };

  // Internal state
  var state = {
    i: 0,
    len: settings.text.length
  };
  
  (function writeLetter() {
    if (state.i >= state.len) return settings.complete();
    settings.element.innerHTML += settings.text.charAt(state.i);
    state.i++;
    setTimeout(writeLetter, settings.speed);
  })();
}

function fader() {
  $("#fade").fadeIn("slow");
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Call the function with options
  typeWriter({
    element: document.getElementById("type"),
    text: "Hello world!",
    speed: 50,
    complete: fader
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="type"></h2>
<div id="fade" style="display: none">I'm fading!</div>
```